# __getattr__ to return index of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the index (ID) of elements of a list, and be able to call it by their name as an attribute.

```
class Page_ids(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.values = ['PAGE1', 'PAGE2', 'PAGE3', 'PAGE4']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.values.index(name)

print(Page_ids.PAGE3)
```

In this example, the print should return 2, but it returns :

```
AttributeError: type object 'Page_ids' has no attribute 'PAGE3'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `__getattr__` will be called when you access attributes on an _instance_ of `Page_ids`, not the class itself.

Comment: And could it be done while calling the class itself? (Metaclass?)

Comment: My understanding is that you could define `__getattr__` on a metaclass if that is what you want.

Comment: Of course, even if you get it to work using metaclasses, `__init__` won't be called and `self.values` would not be defined, so you'd need to completely change the entire implementation if that's what you want.

Comment: What about using  `SimpleNamespace(**dict(zip([f'PAGE{x}' for x in range(1, 5)], range(4))))` from the `types` standard library?

Comment: It's unclear why you are using a class here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally succeeded, I was relying on a structure used in Python2, not working in Python3.

Here is my new code for Python 3 :

```
class Meta(type):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.values.index(name)
    def name_of(self, i):
        return self.values[i]

class Page_ids(object, metaclass=Meta):
    values = ['PAGE1', 'PAGE2', 'PAGE3', 'PAGE4']

print(Page_ids.PAGE3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`__getattr__` is called only on an **instance** of the class, so you need to create one.

```py
class Page_ids(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.values = ['PAGE1', 'PAGE2', 'PAGE3', 'PAGE4']

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.values.index(name)

page = Page_ids()
print(page.PAGE3)
```

Comment: You could also call `print(Page_ids().PAGE3)`.

Comment: Right, but then you won't be able to access the same instance again.